# How to get thumbnail URL with SQL Queries in WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

I want to get the thumbnail URL from SQL query.

I tried this SQL query:

```
p.ID,
  p.post_title,
  meta_value,
  t.name AS product_category,
  t.term_id AS product_id,
  t.slug AS product_slug,
  tt.term_taxonomy_id AS tt_term_taxonomia,
  tr.term_taxonomy_id AS tr_term_taxonomia,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as price,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_regular_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as regular_price,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sale_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sale_price,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as image
FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON pm1.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE p.post_type in('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY p.ID,p.post_title;
```

But it not showing desired result.

Comment: you want to do whole thing by SQL query? or a little PHP code will also do?

Comment: http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail/ there is a readymade function for it, you could look in at that function to derive the sql

Comment: @RaunakGupta i want to do whole thing by SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom field plugin .

Then create fields and link post this plugin is very easy and fast performance.

Comment: I want run with SQL query in php code, not use function api wordpress